# add multiple functions into one in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and I'm just trying out some stuff and I want to know if the following is possible.

I want to add multiple functions into one. My functions are stored in an object (`functionObj`) and I want to add them to my main Object. How many or which is depending on the input(=string).

```
myObj.fnc = function(){ console.log('defaultfunction');

functionObj = { 
a: function(){ console.log('dostuff')},
b: function(){ console.log('dootherstuff');},
//morefunctions
}

// input something like 'a b'
function callmethods(fncstrings){
var functions = fncstrings.split(" ");
for (var f in functions){
myObj.fnc += functionObj[functions[f]]; //this does obviously not work
}
```

If I call `myObj.fnc` I want to get the output of all three functions.

Comment: What's the point to this, besides making brittle code?

Comment: learning by doing

Comment: @woodyplz Please don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly you could do something like this.

```js
var myObj = {}

myObj.fnc = function(){ console.log('defaultfunction')};

var functionObj = { 
  a: function(){ console.log('dostuff')},
  b: function(){ console.log('dootherstuff')}
};

// input something like 'a b'
function callmethods (fncstrings) {
  fncstrings.split(" ").forEach(function(name) {
      var fn = functionObj[name],
        prev = myObj.fnc;


      myObj.fnc = function() {
        var out = prev.apply(this, arguments)
        fn.apply(this, arguments);

        return out;
      };

    }
  );
}


callmethods('a b');

myObj.fnc();
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible in JS or any other language that I am aware of.

The problem here is that there is no acceptable way of adding two functions. Simpler example would be:

```
var a = function(x) { console.log(x) };
var b = function(y, z) { console.log(y+z) };
var c = a + b;
```

So in this case, c just doesn't make sense in any way. Is it a function? If yes, what parameters does it take? How many? If so, what does it do? Does it execute a and b? If yes, how does it do that? And many more questions can be asked in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant add two functions together. I think the best you are going to get is

```
function callmethods(fncstrings){
    var functions = fncstrings.split(" ");
    for (var f in functions){
        functionObj[functions[f]]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
let myObj = {}
myObj.fnc = {} // Make it an object

functionObj = {
    a : function () { console.log('dostuff') },
    b : function () { console.log('dootherstuff'); },
    // more functions
}

Object.keys( functionObj ).forEach( funcName => { // This will iterate over ["a","b"]
     myObj.fnc[ funcName ] = functionObj[ funcName ]
})
```

This will append functions `a` and `b` to `myObj.fnc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to **overwrite** the value of `myObj.fnc` yes, you can, but you don't do it my concatenating functions. You'd have to just create a new function that calls all the `a`, `b`, etc. functions you want.

It'd look something like this:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.fnc = function(){ console.log('defaultfunction') };

functionObj = { 
  a: function(){ console.log('a')},
  b: function(){ console.log('b')},
  c: function(){ console.log('c')}
};

// input something like 'a b', rewrites myObj.fnc
function callmethods(function_strings){
  var functions = function_strings.split(" ");
  functions = functions.map(function(c) {
    return functionObj[c]
  });

  myObj.fnc = function() {
    functions.forEach(function(fn) {
      fn();
    });
  }
}
```

```
myObj.fnc();  // Outputs 'defaultfunction'

callmethods('a b'); // Doesn't output anything yet, overwrites `myObj.fnc`

myObj.fnc(); // Outputs 'a' and 'b'

callmethods('b c'); // Doesn't output anything yet, overwrites `myObj.fnc`

myObj.fnc(); // Outputs 'b' and 'c'
```